# How to use verify in ruby test unit

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver

So I always written scripts using perl
but making an attempt with Ruby, so this question may sound real silly but ill make a  go.

I am writing Selenium Webdriver scripts in ruby Test::Unit
Below is some sample code.

```
 def test_runit
    @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfq").send_keys "selenium"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "gbqfb").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Selenium - Web Browser Automation").click
    assert(@driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("administration tasks"),"the assert works")
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Support").click
  end
```

With an output

```
 ruby runit.rb 
Loaded suite runit
Started
.
Finished in 9.732149 seconds.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

While testing I need to check if text is present on the page.
Using `assert` works just fine.
But if it fails the test ends there and there and does not proceed any further.

In perl I could you some thing like  `verify` which basically marks something as failed and proceed ahead.

I am hoping to get a result like this

```
ruby runit.rb 
Loaded suite runit
Started
.
Finished in 9.732149 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertion, 1 failure, 0 errors
```

But verify does not work for ruby test Unit or may be i am doing it wrong.

Can some one point me to some sample code? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!
One would need to use rescue.
thanks for responding back.

```
begin
    assert(@driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("text to check"),"the assert works")
rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError
    @verification_errors << $!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard that Ruby has the "verify" function which is similar to perl's, since "assert" means, if false, program stops immediately.

I suggest you re-implement your code as and give it a "nil guard":

```
body_element = @driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body")
if body_element
  assert(body_element.text.include?("administration tasks"),"the assert works")
end
```

Comment: The problem is that body element always exists and the check is on the text "administration tasks". But apart form that that program stopping issue is still not solved as the assert if fails will stop the script immediately.

Comment: To change the course of the question a bit, whats to be done to update the "failures" aspect in the test results?

Comment: the test case stops once the "assert" fails, that's the way of unit test's. I think :).  BTW, you could take a look at "ensure".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed. You need to rescue the command.

However, you can easily create a verify method similar to this in your test helpers

```
 def verify
   $verification_errors = [] if $verification_errors.nil?
   assert yield
 rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError => afe
   $verification_errors << afe
   puts "ERROR: #{afe.message}"
 end
```

And then you could call it something like this:

```
 verify{ @driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("foobar") }
```

At the end of your tests, during the teardown, you will want to check to see if there are any verification errors:

```
 assert $verification_errors.empty? or $verification_errors.nil?
```